# Es posibe hacer una consulta con datos ya sacados de otra consulta?

Tags: php, mysql, excel, phpexcel

Tengo un problema lo que quiero hacer es que al consultar:

```
$resultados = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM tbarchivos");
while($extraido = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultados)){
    echo "  <input type='checkbox' name='Check' /> ".$extraido['Nombre']." <br>";
}
```

Y quiero que esa consulta se mande a otra pagina osea cuando seleccione varios checkboxs, haga que los nombre que ya seleccione aparezcan en un excel el codigo que tengo de excel es este:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbarchivos";
$resultado = $link->query($sql);
$fila = 7; //Establecemos en que fila inciara a imprimir los datos

//Objeto de PHPExcel
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(10);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A6', 'ID');

while($extraido = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$fila, $extraido['Codigo']);
}
```

A lo que me refiero es que mi codigo es que haga una consulta y los datos de esa tabla se manden al excel lo que quiero es mandar los checkbox seleccionados a la consulta y que asi aparezcan en el excel, ese el codigo que tengo no es asi pero lo resumi a una sola variable pero tengo mas.

Comment: Hola  me gustaría saber si cuando seleccionas los checkbox para convertir esos nombre presionas algún boton ?  que metodo utiliza el formularaio `GET` o `POST`

Comment: Si se utiliza un boton y el metodo es post

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes cambiar `name='Check'` en los checkbox por `name='Check[]'` y agregar el atributo `value=""`, esto hará que se envíen los valores seleccionados en un array.

```
while($extraido = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultados)) {
    echo "  <input type='checkbox' name='Check[]' value='".$extraido['Codigo']."' />".$extraido['Nombre']." <br>";
}
```

Para obtener los valores de este array en la otra interfaz solo verificar que exista cada item en el arreglo:

```
$fila = 7; 
//Objeto de PHPExcel
$objPHPExcel  = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(10);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A6', 'ID');
$i=0;
while(isset($_REQUEST['Check'][$i])) {
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$fila, $_REQUEST['Check'][$i]); 
    $fila++;
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Gracias pero lo que ocupo es que los checkboxs tiene un nombre de la base de datos y quiero que mi codigo al seleccionar esos checkbox la consulta de la otra pagina me mande todos los campos de ese nombre y de los demas nombre que seleccione y no se como hacer eso,usando un `select * from tbarchivos` y no se si se pueda usar un WHERE y poner el codigo id de los checkbox seleccionados para que me traiga todos los campos de la BD